# How to select name by 2 fields in another 2 tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I got confused trying after making several searches on google to find a way to do the following:

- I have table called students that contains 3 colums `(student_id(primarykey), firstname,lastname)`,
- the second table called courses contains 2 columns `(course code,course_name)` and
- the third table called registration contains `(student_id,course_code)`,

I need to select the name of students that are registered in course that includes the word for example "Structures" in the course_name field.

For example (consider the snap-shot)
[image: Example]

Regardless the concat of the firstname and lastname, this is easy to do it.

So I will get these student names : SomeOne & GoodStudent

P.S. I created table Registration by inserting from the first two tables together.

So I tried like the following:

```
select concat(firstname,lastname) 
from students 
  left join registration 
where students.student_id = registration.student_id 
  and registration.course_code like 'Structure%';
```

Comment: You need to work a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) and then check [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: Yes I'm using the left join and like actually, But the thing is I'm so confused that the course_name and the student name is in two different tables and registration has id which is common with students table and has course_code which is common with courses table. So I tried like the following: select concat(firstname,lastname) from students left join registration where students.student_id = registration.student_id and registration.course_code like 'Structure%';

Sorry as I'm junior and I really tried to search using different phrases so that I can find a case similar to mine but failed.

Comment: That query is not valid. `left join` requires `on`.

Comment: And you need to join all 3 tables (so two joins, not one).

Comment: Ah I understand, this is just new to me to join 3 tables and it make a sense, So joining 3 tables syntax will be similar to joining 2 tables syntax?

Comment: Yep... you have `t1 JOIN t2 ON t2.xxx = t1.xxx JOIN t3 ON t3.yyy = t1.yyy`

Comment: I tried it this way: 

 select concat_ws('',firstname,lastname) from students left join courses on courses.course_name = students.student_id left join registration on registration.student_id = students.student_id where courses.course_name like 'Development%';

But it didn't work even this
 select concat_ws('',firstname,lastname) from students left join courses on courses.course_name = students.student_id left join registration on registration.student_id = students.student_id;

:-( It's really confusing me and online resources has nothing clear to explain such case I have.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows in the table on the left side, and matching rows where found from the table on the right side. So, if students is on the left side (as  above), all students will be returned. You probably want the course on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as correctly mentioned in comments - LEFT JOIN not proper choice in Your case, even if You fix the syntax (JOIN require ON condition)

You need use INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(s1.firstname,s1.lastname) as full_name 
FROM students s1
INNER JOIN registration r1 ON s1.student_id = r1.student_id 
INNER JOIN courses c1 ON c1.course_code = r1.course_code 
WHERE c1.course_name LIKE '%Structure%';
```

or You need swap tables

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(s1.firstname,s1.lastname) as full_name
FROM courses c1 
LEFT JOIN registration r1 ON c1.course_code = r1.course_code
LEFT JOIN students s1 ON s1.student_id = r1.student_id
WHERE c1.course_name LIKE '%Structure%';
```

as You can see LIKE - must have % from both ends for found what You are looking for

Comment: Thanks very much @a_vlad it works smoothly and as intended.

Thank you guys also for trying to help.